unable to connect onpremisesql to adf
Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support. Server: '', Database: '', User: ''. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access. A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

I have tried install the self-hosted integration runtime and unable to connect the on-premise SQL server got below error while connecting in ADF:



A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

According to this MS document This error occurs when you try to make an encrypted connection to SQL Server using a non-verifiable certificate. Enable Trust server certificate in linked service and try to connect with self- hosted integration runtime it will connect successfully as shown below:

Along with that make sure you have entered correct credentials. For more information you can refer to similar SO thread.
